# AngularJS repopulating checkboxes for edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new to AngularJS and am trying to move from purely server-side to making the magic happen in real time with AngularJS on the front-end.

I have a user that can have multiple permissions. When creating a new user, you can select multiple checkboxes, all that works fine. I'm having trouble repopulating the checkboxes for when the user wants to make a change to the user's permissions.

I am using the checklist-model directives, found here http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

In the database, I have a users, permissions, and users_permissions tables.

**UsersController -Laravel**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::with('permissions')->find($id);
    return $user;
}
```

**UserController -Angular**

```
Users.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'User', 'Permission', function($scope, $routeParams, User, Permission) {
    $scope.user = User.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
    $scope.permissions = Permission.query();
}]);
```

Because I attached the permissions to the user on the server-side, when I `console.log($scope.user)` I get this object

[image]

Now for the view

**single-user.html**

```
   <h4>Manage Permissions</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label ng-repeat="permission in permissions">

        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.permissions" checklist-value="permission.id" class="checkbox-inline">
            {{ permission.display_name }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I thought that I could create an assigned variable in the controller that contained the `$scope.user.permissions.id` and then compare those values against the `$scope.permissions.id` and if they matched then check the checkbox.

When I tried to create `$scope.assigned = $scope.user.permissions.id` and console.log(assigned) then I was just returned undefined.

I'm not sure how to create an array of assigned permissions to compare against the standard permissions, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.get` and `Permission.query` look like they're using `$resource`.  These will return promises that will (if all goes well) resolve to your data rather than returning the data itself.  The calls are asynchronous.  So you need to pass a function parameter that gets called when the async calls complete.

When you got `undefined` during the console.log test, it was because in `$scope.user.permissions.id`, `$scope.user` is actually a promise (`$q`), not the object you were expecting.  You were basically evaluating `$q.permissions.id`, which is undefined.

```
User.get({ id: $routeParams.id }, function(user) { $scope.user = user; });
Permission.query(function(permissions) { $scope.permissions = permissions; });
```

Or you can try something like this (not 100% sure on this one)

```
$q.all(
    User.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
    Permission.query();
).then(function(user, permissions) { $scope.user = user, $scope.permissions = permissions });
```

See below for more details on how you can chain actions to the `User.get()` and `Permission.query()` calls:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Neither of the solutions worked, but what you are saying about promises makes sense. I believe this is a step in the right direction, thanks @scottt732